# How did Stack Overflow implement tags search before migrating to Lucene?

Tags: discussion, search, tag-search

From what I found about SO schema I know it keeps a Tags column on Posts table with tags in format: [tag1][tag2]. Also I am under the impression it was using SQL Server FTS then it migrated to lucene.net then to Elasticsearch. [New Stack Exchange Search, Try it out!](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/76621/new-stack-exchange-search-try-it-out?lq=1)

I am curious about this because SO has tags containing "-" and SQL Server Full-Text Search finds this as word breaker. One solution to solve this would be to use `%like%` but this would cause full table scan, or just replace special chars with predefined keywords like proposed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13116783/1612133).

So did it replace word breakers or was it another solution?

Comment: It doesn't search tags, it searches the title and body of a post.  The tags table is only ever checked if the search query contains an explicit [tag].  That's an exact match only.

Comment: ok, I was assuming a search like "[c#] or [asp.net] -[ajax]" is mapped into a ContainsTable FTS on Posts.Tags column, without hitting the Tags table

Comment: In [SEDE](http://data.stackexchange.com/) there is  a tags table and a posttags table that are fully normalized. Find the data dictionary [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2677/database-schema-documentation-for-the-public-data-dump-and-sede)

Comment: This is related, and interesting reading: http://blog.marcgravell.com/2014/04/technical-debt-case-study-tags.html

Comment: @Matt, thanks...that post was what I looking for

Comment: I think you want to tags this as support instead of discussion.